# No mapping for the Unicode character Exception

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, unicode

In **C#** and **Windows Phone SDK** I have got this exception: "**WinRT information: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page**.".

I do on some **Pivot Application for Windows Phone 8** and I need **json** file with informations, which contains characters like **'á' or 'ý'**. How can I add these characters without the exception?

This is method, where is the exception:

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)        
{  
            // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
            var sampleDataGroup = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync("Group-1");
            this.DefaultViewModel[FirstGroupName] = sampleDataGroup;
}
```

and the json file looks like something like that:

```
{"Groups":[
  {
    "UniqueId": "Group-1",
    "Title": "Group Title: 1",
    "Subtitle": "Group subtitle: 1",
    "ImagePath": "Assets/DarkGray.png",
    "Description" : "Group Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempor scelerisque lorem in vehicula. Aliquam tincidunt, lacus ut sagittis tristique, turpis massa volutpat augue, eu rutrum ligula ante a ante",
    "Items":
    [
      {
        "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-1",
        "Title": "ý" /* !!!!this is the problem!!!! */,
        "Subtitle": "Item Subtitle: 1",
        "ImagePath": "Assets/LightGray.png",
        "Description" : "Item Description: Pellentesque porta, mauris quis interdum vehicula, urna sapien ultrices velit, nec venenatis dui odio in augue. Cras posuere, enim a cursus convallis, neque turpis malesuada erat, ut adipiscing neque tortor ac erat.",
        "Content" : "Curabitur class aliquam vestibulum nam curae maecenas sed integer cras phasellus."
      },
```

Comment: Presumably there's some code involved here - can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: 1) What serializer are you using to deserialize your JSON?  Can you show us the code that does reads and deserializes it?  2) [JSON](http://www.json.org/) allows for escaping of unicode characters.  What if you replace `"ý"` with [`"\u00fd"`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fd/index.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks \u00fd works! By the way, the serializer was the dafault in Windows Phone SDK:

```
private async Task GetSampleDataAsync()
        {
            if (this._groups.Count != 0)
                return;

            Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json");

            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
            string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

            foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
            {
                JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
                SampleDataGroup group = new SampleDataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                            groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                            groupObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                            groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                            groupObject["Description"].GetString());

                foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
                {
                    JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                    group.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["Content"].GetString()));
                }
                this.Groups.Add(group);
            }
        }
```